Parent categories not in url bad for SEO?
Magento by default does not include the full string or parent categories in any category URL only the very last
So a category that on a none Magento site might be
https://www.rattandirect.co.uk/garden-furniture/rattan-garden-sofa-sets/3-seater-sofa-sets
on magento it will be https://www.rattandirect.co.uk/3-seater-sofa-sets
my question is, is this bad for SEO?
Some search terms and KW's are in that longer URL, in this case, "rattan garden sofa set". In other cases, it might be a product's material, colour or amount of seats or whatever
Not all the product titles would say this.........
I believe there is a way to give the 'breadcrumb' to Google in the rich data, but I want to ask, on face valve, is this good or bad?
Here is a video explainer for anyone who is amazing and can help :)
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/30539341?key=c7698ae61bc1fff72714ef9882e23593

A friend of mine took a look and offered the following
{"@context":"https:\/\/schema.org","@type":"BreadcrumbList","itemListElement":[{"@type":"ListItem","position":1,"item":{"@id":"https:\/\/posh.co.uk\/","name":"Home"}},{"@type":"ListItem","position":2,"item":{"@id":"https:\/\/posh.co.uk\/garden.html","name":"Garden"}},{"@type":"ListItem","position":3,"item":{"@id":"https:\/\/posh.co.uk\/metal-furniture.html","name":"Metal Furniture"}},{"@type":"ListItem","position":4,"item":{"@id":"https:\/\/posh.co.uk\/dining-sets.html","name":"Dining Sets"}}]}
That's where your breadcrumbs pull in
based on that
It's actually set up better than others
Magento typically creates both URLs https://posh.co.uk/garden/dining-sets.html and https://posh.co.uk/dining-sets.html. With https://posh.co.uk/garden/dining-sets.html canonicalizing to https://posh.co.uk/dining-sets.html.
As typically all of your traffic goes to the non-canonical version. There's no benefit of it that can't be created via a "virtual silo" - more on that in a minute. Plus, if you ever migrated away, you end up loosing all the cRUX data (something my flavour of SEO and all my tests point to as a massive factor, supported by Google leak).
You can't redirect canonicals as they're typically not in the index but cRUX data passed through the canonical
Who ever has set this up that way for you knows what they're doing and has disabled the Magento URLs that it spits out like there's no tomorrow.
You have the best setup IMO
The nested structure, i.e. /category/sub-category used to be important. But it's not a thing to focus on anymore. As long as they're all linked together, you're fine. AND this way you're inadvertently fixing something that causes an even bigger issue in Magento's infrastructure.
Sorry mate, would love to take some cash off you and "fix" this, but you have the ideal setup "
